# Black screen when i try to install ubuntu 18 via usb

Tags: boot, system-installation, laptop, intel-graphics

I'm trying to install ubuntu for some time now,whatever i do(without or with installing) i get black screen . Tried every single option(disable fast boot,disable secure boot,nomodeset etc) but still end up with black screen.

hp envy x360 - i7 5500u intel hd graphics 5500

Bootable usb is working,tried on my roommates laptop also HP.

Anybody ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the computer POST? Are you able to enter the BIOS?

Comment: yes I am and what do you mean by POST ?

Comment: "Power On Self Test." It occurs prior to loading the operating system and detects if the hardware is present. However, it sounds like the hardware all works. When you have a black screen, try pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` to see if a console login appears. Does this work?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a graphics problem. To confirm, please follow these steps:

- Power on your machine with the Ubuntu boot-able installation USB connected.
- You might need to hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> at boot to see this screen:

[image]

- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the **Other Options** menu.
- Select **nomodeset** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> so it becomes selected with an `x` in front of it like in the image above.
- Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> once.
- Select **Try Ubuntu without installing** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Now try Ubuntu. If it works fine on your system, please move on to installation.

You will need to connect your computer to the Internet and make sure to select **Install third-party software for graphics** when you are presented with this screen:

[image]

---

If you manage to install Ubuntu successfully. Then you solved the installation issue.

If all good, then well done.

If you require more help with configuring your graphics, then you are most welcome to open a new question and we will help.

Best of luck

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. When I boot I end up with GNU GRUB v2.02 screen,so  after presing e, I input nomodest before quiet splash. In the end end up with black screen.

Comment: @DautDaut can you put your full setup? How you added nomodest? It is stuck and nothing happens