# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on iMac 21,5-inch late 2009

Tags: boot, system-installation, mac

I would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my iMac 21.5-inch late 2009 with the following specifications:

- CPU: 3,06 GHZ Intel Core 2 Duo
- RAM: 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
- GPU: ATI Radeon HD 4670 256 MB

For the installation process I am using a bootable USB-Stick.

Whenever I try to boot my screen splits up into 4 smaller screens which makes it hard to see anything on the screen and then I have to manually shut the iMac down.

How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 run on my old iMac?

[image: splitscreen after booting Ubuntu from usb]

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1182214/968501

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the solution just if you hold CMD + v at the start of Macintosh you will be in the verbose mode 20 there you will be able to add the nomodeset instruction in the grub

Comment: Hello,
How exactly am I possible to add the nomodeset?

I tried your suggestions.
Once I am in verbose mode (I believe it is), my Mac is going through some code and straight afterwards it loads the user login-page.

Could you provide me witrh a more detailed instruction, please?