# Installation CD doesn't boot - how to add nomodeset?

Tags: boot, system-installation

My system (Ubuntu MATE 16.04) got corrupted and it only boots when I add the option nomodeset to grub. I tried to reinstall the system from CD or USB stick (I used Ubuntu MATE 18.04), but the system doesn't even load from CD. First it shows the NTB splash screen (msi), then it prints ISOLINUX..., then it shows splash screen with the keyboard and accessibility icons and then it returns to the beginning again.

I held Shift key and could check the option nomodeset, but it didn't help. It returned to the msi splash screen and started to boot from beginning again.

Just now I am writing from a system loaded from rescue CD - it booted without problem. Is there a trick I could use for Ubuntu to boot, or is there a clone of Ubuntu that would boot (like the Rescue CD)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when i try to install ubuntu 18 via usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but when I checked nomodeset and tried to boot Ubuntu, it returned to the NTB BIOS splash screen (msi) and then it tried to boot from CD again. It is repeating all over until I switch the notebook off.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to boot and install a new version of the system. I had to switch to UEFI boot option in BIOS and then I was able to boot from a USB stick. I installed only Ubuntu software, but after reboot the computer hanged again. After I installed everything including third-party SW, the system "survived" reboot. My guess is that all the troubles were caused by NVidia graphic card and its drivers.