# Black screen with white lines at the top

Tags: system-installation, laptop, windows-10, usb-installation, toshiba

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an old Toshiba 64x laptop that I never used. When I put in the USB drive which works on other computers rather than loading the Ubuntu installation page, it just shows a black screen with white lines of varying sizes. I have already turned off Secure Boot.

[image: black screen]

Comment: It tries to show the start screen on your monitor - but doesn't have any idea what kind of graphics card you have... Either the card is broken or very exotic. Toshiba is known for very bad Bioses - they tamper with the DSDT tables later to get their stuff running. That might explain, why a patched windows may run on it. Can you switch graphic cards in bios? Then try to set for intel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when i try to install ubuntu 18 via usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb)

Comment: How would I switch my graphics card in bios? It says I have Radeon HD Graphics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was fixed when loading it from CSM boot rather than UEFI boot. I don’t know why it worked, but after one or two error messages it began the Ubuntu installation