# Stuck at black screen with Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, live-usb, usb-installation, 20.04

I just made a bootable USB to install 20.04. I then boot my laptop, and selected installation from the USB drive. After that, the screen showed up where it ran some disk checks and now, it's stuck. It's been like half an hour.

After disk check:

[image]

During disk check:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when i try to install ubuntu 18 via usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb)

Comment: Thanks. But I fixed it by turning it off and starting again.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it by powering off and removing the USB drive and then begin installation.