# Can't access BIOS ASUS k56c

Tags: boot, live-usb, bios, acpi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my ASUS k56cb laptop. Now I can't access either the BIOS screen or Ubuntu 20.04. There's just a black screen, and it doesn't boot. How can I reinstall my system? I got this screen when I tried to boot from a USB stick: `nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios ctor failed, -22`.

[image: ASUS]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen when i try to install Ubuntu 18 via USB](https://askubuntu.com/q/1182211/)