# Problems installing Ubuntu 22.04 on AMD EPYC 9374F / Gigabyte R263-Z30

Tags: system-installation

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on a USB stick, I want to install on a AMD EPYC 9374F computer.

Motherboard is Gigabyte R263-Z30 (rev. AAC1)

I can boot to the USB and select the "Install Linux" option, a load of text wizzes past, but after about 5 seconds the display goes blank and it's dead (does not get to "select your language" part).

I realise the EPYC 9374F is a pretty new machine, can Ubuntu 22.04 even be installed on it? If not, what version of Linux (Ubuntu highly preferred) can I use?

If it should work, how do I progress / debug this?

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182211/black-screen-when-i-try-to-install-ubuntu-18-via-usb

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else: Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 - with HWE install option selected - works great.